# Undefined reference to boost::locale::generator::generate with CMake Project

Tags: c++, linux, boost, cmake, linker

I've recently returned to working on a project using CMake, and I'm having trouble getting it to build again.

The issue is that at the final link step, g++ says that it can't find a reference to a boost locale generate function, even though I've used find_package to get boost and link it.

Here's the step which is failing:

```
/usr/bin/c++ -m64 -O3 -DNDEBUG -m64 CMakeFiles/sable.dir/main.cpp.o -o ../sable  -Wl,-rpath,$HOME/.conan/data/yaml-cpp/0.6.3/_/_/package/607c93de2fe0fd7a16b1a720c8a32bd38084b7f0/lib libsable_lib.a $HOME/.conan/data/yaml-cpp/0.6.3/_/_/package/607c93de2fe0fd7a16b1a720c8a32bd38084b7f0/lib/libyaml-cpp.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_locale.so.1.74.0 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_chrono.so.1.74.0 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_system.so.1.74.0 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_thread.so.1.74.0 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_atomic.so.1.74.0 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicui18n.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicuuc.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicudata.so -ldl
/usr/bin/ld: libsable_lib.a(parse.cpp.o): in function `sable::TextParser::TextParser(sable::FontList&&, std::string const&, std::string const&)':
parse.cpp:(.text+0x551b): undefined reference to `boost::locale::generator::generate(std::string const&) const'
```

Here's where I'm finding my dependencies in CMake:

```
find_library(YAML yaml-cpp REQUIRED)
find_package(Boost 1.71.0 REQUIRED COMPONENTS locale)
find_package(ICU 66.1 REQUIRED COMPONENTS in uc dt)
message(STATUS ${Boost_LIBRARIES})

list(
    APPEND SABLE_LIBRARIES

    ${Boost_LIBRARIES}
    ${ICU_LIBRARIES}
)
```

And here's where I'm linking everything:

```
add_library(sable_lib STATIC ${SABLE_SOURCE_FILES})

target_link_libraries(sable_lib PUBLIC coverage_config ${YAML} ${SABLE_LIBRARIES} ${SABLE_FS_LIBRARIES} ${SABLE_PLATFORM_LIBRARIES})

add_executable(
    sable

    "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/main.cpp"
)

target_link_libraries(
    sable sable_lib
)
```

This definitely worked at some point in the past. The only thing that's changed is that I switched to getting one of my dependencies from Conan, but it's not boost or the ICU components. I'm building on Kubuntu 22.04 with GCC 11, if that makes any difference.

Comment: "This definitely worked at some point in the past" - Then why don't you checkout that "point in the past" in your source control system and compare it to the current state?

Comment: I did end up doing that, more or less, though it didn't reveal anything useful. Turned out to be an issue in my conan profile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out: in my default conan profile, I had the setting `compiler.libcxx=libstdc++`, when it should have been `compiler.libcxx=libstdc++11`.

Comment: I think the correct lib should be automatically selected by telling the compiler&linker (via switch), which dialect to use.